# Rcraid-dkms compilation error in apt install

Tags: apt, 22.04, raid, linux-headers

I`m trying install rcraid-dkms in my Ubuntu 22.04.3 system new installation. When I make a

> sudo apt install rcraid-dkms

, the process results in a compilation error because It can not find any .h header file, and my knowledge is so basic in Linux system.
Probably the solution is so simple but I need help.

**UPDATED.-**

I deployed build-essential packet before, and I have the kernel headers installed in my system.

The compilation log is...

```
DKMS make.log for rcraid-8.1.0 for kernel 6.2.0-34-generic (x86_64)
jue 12 oct 2023 09:22:22 CEST
make: se entra en el directorio '/var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src' 
make -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-34-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-34-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
You are using:           gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
ln -sf `basename /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rcblob.x86_64.o .o` /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rcblob.x86_64.o
CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_init.o
CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_msg.o
CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_mem_ops.o
CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_event.o
CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_config.o
CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/vers.o
/var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_config.c:11:10: fatal error: linux/genhd.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
11 | #include <linux/genhd.h>
   |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:260: /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_config.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc.h:97,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_mem_ops.c:43:
/var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_msg_platform.h:30:10: fatal error: stdarg.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
   30 | #include <stdarg.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc.h:97,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_event.c:25:
/var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_msg_platform.h:30:10: fatal error: stdarg.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
   30 | #include <stdarg.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc.h:97,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_msg.c:22:
/var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_msg_platform.h:30:10: fatal error: stdarg.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
   30 | #include <stdarg.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc.h:97,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_init.c:38:
/var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_msg_platform.h:30:10: fatal error: stdarg.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
   30 | #include <stdarg.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:260: /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_mem_ops.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:260: /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_event.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:260: /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_msg.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:260: /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src/rc_init.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2026: /var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-34-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:68: module] Error 2
make: se sale del directorio '/var/lib/dkms/rcraid/8.1.0/build/src'`
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please append your full compilation error

Comment: Have you performed `sudo apt install build-essential` ? If not, do so. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Yes, I performed a sudo apt install build-essential before. And my compilation error is indicated .